# My offer letter doesn’t reflect what was discussed. What should I do?

Tags: salary, startup, equity, stock, offer

I recently received an offer from a small tech start up that just received a round of funding to be their founding sales rep. It’s exciting and I verbally accepted the offer, however when I received the offer in writing, it reflected a different agreement regarding my equity in the company. The way it was presented to me on the phone was that I would be receiving 8,000 shares in the company that would be distributed over time. But on the offer letter it’s listed as options, not shares, meaning I would have to buy into the company to get equity. Big difference I believe. Am I being too nit picky or is this a big deal and worth saying something? They are wanting to move fast and I want to make sure I’m making the right decision so any help would be greatly appreciate.

Comment: Side tip: Don't be rushed into a decision. Make sure all formal documents are cleared up to your satisfaction. IME at a small startup, the guy who had the most drawn-out and strenuous negotiation process had added respect/credibility/deference as a result.

Comment: Make sure you fully understand the difference between options and stock grants specifically with respect to taxes in your locality. In the US you can make a good argument that ISO options are preferable to direct equity grants especially  if the stock isn't traded yet.

Comment: Not an answer, but this may have been an innocent mistake -- whoever you were talking about may not be aware of the difference and didn't realize they were misleading you.

Comment: @Barmar: that is entirely possible. At least in the US options are the "normal" way of equity compensation simply because it's tax-wise the best method for all parties involved.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins Can you say for sure that the respect/credibility/deference was a result of the drawn-out negotiation, or was it that the prior credibility he had that was the reason he could get away with a drawn-out negotiation?

Comment: @HashimAziz: I'd say yes. The principals would talk more about their negotiation process than their other skills or experience (which were in fact kind of shaky). Consider: Business guys mostly can't really evaluate creativity or tech skills, but they can give an assessment on the business negotiation they were directly involved with.

Comment: Do you have coworkers who've been part of prior successful ventures with the same founders? Talk to them. Find out how staff members who came in at about the same time and about the same position in the company were treated. (Also, people who came in later and in more junior positions as well). When it comes to options, the founders' views on staff compensation arguably matter _more_ than what's written in your contract.

Comment: @Hilmar In the US, options are normal for startups.  Established public companies typically give RSUs, because they can never go underwater, and because the tax status is favorable that way.  But either way it should be understood what you're getting.

Comment: Besides shares and options not being quite the same thing, options as part of a compensation package and options as traded in the markets tend to be different. The latter tend to be ATM or close to ATM, while the former (at least for start-ups) generally have a strike price that's close to nominal, relative to the market value, such as $0.25/share. What sort of strike price do you have here?

Comment: There's probably virtually no difference between shares and options here. The shares that you get when you exercise the options are likely common shares that have virtually no value today, so the cost to exercise the option is probably very close to zero. The idea is to give you participation in the company's upside, not a share of the spoils if the company is sold for scrap.

Answer (score 57):

**Call them and get clarification.**

Call them up and tell them you thought you were getting equity rather than options.

How big the difference is depends very much on the price at which you will be offered the options. If it's very low then it's essentially like being given shares. If it's very high then it's little value. Hopefully that is spelled out in the offer letter.

EDIT: Based on the information that this is really an "option" and that "the price will be set by the board of directors", my advice is that this is not a serious part of your compensation. It's icing on the cake, but it's not a part of the cake itself. The directors can choose to make this option very valuable or almost entirely worthless, depending on how they feel. There may be wording that restricts the board to something like a "fair" price, which makes the situation better. Get the company to give you a detailed description of how the options work.

Also "8000 shares" tells you nothing without knowing how many shares of the company exist. It might be 50% of the company, but it might also be 0.05% of the company. Definitely ask how many shares there are and if there are plans to increase that number before you exercise your option. Also ask what the value of each share is now.

Having said that, being in at the ground floor on the ownership of a new company *may* give you the chance of becoming extremely rich if the company does well. Maybe.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is helpful. The offer letter does not reflect a written value for the options. It states “The exercise price will be determined by the board of directors when the option is granted.”

Comment: @Anonymous that means they are not giving you any contractual right to buy any stock below market price. They *might* do it when the "board of directors" feels like it.

Comment: If it's a private company then there might not even be a thing called "market price".

Comment: “The exercise price will be determined by the board of directors when the option is granted.” is standard wording in the US and there is nothing nefarious about it. The board of directors values the company on a regular basis (for legal and tax reasons) and that in turn sets the share price. This a fairly well defined process.

Comment: I'm not saying it's necessarily nefarious, but it does allow the board to set a good price or a bad price, and unless there is something in the wording that restricts their choice then they can set whatever they want.

Comment: @Anonymous Please can you edit the extra information into the question?

Comment: +1 for "It's icing on the cake, but it's not a part of the cake itself." Giving options instead of outright shares is common, as is the total share value amounting to ~0.1% of the company (once they finally vest). Not uncommon nor nefarious, but small enough that it shouldn't majorly influence your decision to accept the offer.

Comment: @DJClayworth: There is. When we needed a number and there had been no sales we used the account's evaluation to get something that acts like market price.

Comment: @Joshua Valuing a private company that has no sales and no working product is a huge exercise in guesswork, even for an accountant. When will the product be ready? How many will it sell? Even an accountant is hugely dependent on the product manager's estimates for the first, and the head of sales for the second, neither of whom are unbiased.

Comment: @DJClayworth: We found the tax man doesn't care that the account's number is dodgy because they can't produce a better one.

Comment: @Joshua It's not about tax. If the estimate is being used to set the price of shares, the OP can find they have paid $10 for the shares because that's what the "estimate" of the company's value was. Later it turns out that the product is going to be a year late and that means the shares are only worth $5.

Comment: @DJClayworth and beyond that, it's going be VERY difficult liquidating these shares from an unlisted company. They're effectively worth $0 because nobody is going to buy them. It'll most likely stay that way for much longer than most people think, and it can easily evaporate into actual nothingness because large majority of startups fail.

Comment: @Nelson A good point. The expectation is that anyone with any investment in a startup hangs on to their investment until the company is bought out/goes public, and then makes a pile of money. Of course that means potentially waiting a long time (and with a good chance of coming away with nothing)

Comment: Just keep in mind the amount of people who have shares from when Microsoft, Apple, IBM, Google were formed, is a very small percentage of the employees that have ever worked at those companies.  Even then the amount of people who have, an amount of shares that make them independently wealth is even smaller.  My point, you really should treat the shares you receive as a bonus, most shares in a private company end up being worthless. There are exceptions, I know somebody who had ConnectWise shares, company was purchased and they got a nice payout.

Comment: Personally, I would email them, then I would call them 2 minutes after sending out that email. I think keeping a written record is important. It avoid any further misunderstandings over the phone.

Comment: @DJClayworth First, options are almost always used because giving stock forces the recipient to pay taxes immediately on illiquid shares unable to be sold. Secondly, option pricing is based on a valuation appraisal, and no board will raise the price as they use options to attract talent. The appraisal will rely heavily on the most recent investment round valuation, discounted for lack of liquidity and the lesser rights of common shares. Finally, options don't have to be purchased in the short run (usually you have 10 years post vesting), OP can wait until IPO or company sale to buy them.

Comment: Typo: "very valuable of almost entirely worthless" - "of" should be "or"

Comment: It makes absolutely no sense to treat options in a small tech startup as a less "serious" part of compensation than shares. In the US, as long as you have a long exercise window (e.g. 10 years) and the exercise price is set at "FMV" at date of issue, options in an early-stage startup whose long-term plan involves massive growth are arguably *preferable to receive* than the same number of actual shares, because you still get most of the upside if the company succeeds and grows 10x or more in value, but you don't have to pay the taxman anything when the options are granted (or when they vest).

Answer (score 39):

**tl,dr: Stock plans are complicated. Before you engage make sure you read the documentation for the employee stock plan and make sure you understand fully. Ask an adviser if you need to. It's possible that options are better.**

> Big difference I believe.

Yes, but make sure you fully understand which one is better. A location tag would have really helped here.

In the US options (and specifically ISO options) are the "normal" way of managing equity for startup hires. This is simply because options are arguably better for anyone involved especially if the stock is not traded publicly.

The main is reason is tax treatment. Direct stock grants are taxable as income the moment you receive them even if you can't do anything with the stock. Let's say you get 8000 shares at a strike price of $1. If you are in the 22% bracket you will have to pay $1760 on income tax on the stock. If the stock later tanks or the company goes under, you get nothing in return. You may be able to claim this as capital losses in the future but that's complicated.

With ISO options, you don't pay any taxes on the grant or the exercise (disregarding AMT for now). You only pay taxes when you sell and this point you have an actual gain to show for it.

It's entirely possible that person on the phone was just sloppy when they made the offer. Since options are the standard, may have assumed that you knew this and when they said "you'll get 8000 shares over 4 years" they meant "you get 8000 options that will vest over 4 years".

Comment: "Strike price" applies to options. For actual shares, it's Fair Market Value (although figuring out FMV can be difficult if the company is private).

Answer (score 13):

The only thing that counts is what is in writing, in the offer letter. Recall the saying that a verbal promise is not worth the paper it is written on. Call them, ask for clarification and carefully check that everything that is important to you actually ends up in the offer letter in writing. If they tell you verbally you get shares and the offer letter says options you will get options.

Answer (score 12):

Inform them that there is a mistake in the written offer because it does not reflect what was verbally agreed upon and send them a correction with the terms as you understood them.

Then the ball is in their court again. They might retract their offer and make a new one that is closer to yours, or insist on their original offer. What to do with that is up to you.

But keep in mind that shares in a startup are usually not a very good deal and should never be considered an alternative to a fair market-rate salary. The reason is that the future of a startup is (despite what the founders will probably claim) in most cases very uncertain. First of all, most startups fail within the first couple years, turning all the shares into garbage. But even if you believe that this startup is different and will certainly succeed, there is a lot they can do later that could make your shares worthless. For example, they could issue more shares later that dilute yours to a negligible value. Or they could merge and split and restructure their company empire a couple times, and in the end the company your shares are in isn't the one you work for  anymore. Or where the money is made. Or that still exists.

So receiving shares in a startup is probably not a hill you want to die on. Salary is, though.

Comment: "For example, they could issue more shares later that dilute yours to a negligible value." They have a fiduciary duty to maintain the value of the stock. If more shares are issued, it should be in exchange for an equivalent amount of value, keeping the per share price the same.

Comment: "*For example, they could issue more shares later that dilute yours to a negligible value.*" This is a myth. Issuing share shas no effect on the value of existing shares because the company, that is the existing shares, own the new shares. Trading those shares for something else of value doesn't reduce the value of existing shares either. You misunderstand dilution if you think it reduces the value of existing shares.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz *"Trading those shares for something else **of value** doesn't reduce the value of existing shares either. "* See the problem here? We already know that this is a company that issues shares to pay employees, not just to raise capital. When they keep doing that, they are indeed devaluing their shares.

Comment: @Philipp No, they're not. The expected value the future employees will bring is greater than the reduction in the percentage of future revenue that each share will represent. That's the *only* reason they're issuing those shares.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz ...and other lies to tell to early investors.

Comment: @Philipp If you're going to argue that the company is badly run and the stockholders are getting the short end of the stick on management's business decisions, stock issued to compensate employees is an incredibly strange place to start. Why not complain about cash used to compensate employees --that comes directly and immediately out of the pockets of the stockholders.

Answer (score 3):

Just one dimension that hasn't been touched on here yet:

Regardless of the realities surrounding the shares vs options at this company, I think the most important dimension of this situation is that you and your future employer establish a precedent for having difficult conversations naturally, quickly getting on the same page, and working together for mutual benefit.  Neither one of you wants to START your relationship with a disagreement.  That could lead to one or both of you seeing your interaction as transactional instead of rich and interdependent.  As a result, I would recommend:

1. Talk to them quickly.  Don't let the matter fester.  Don't ruminate over what they might be thinking or how things could go.  Nip those kinds of things in the bud and go have an open conversation.
2. Give them all the benefit of the doubt.  In fact, go into this thinking things like, "They really want to give me the best they can," "They want a founding sales rep. who is THRILLED to be here," and "If I really needed something difficult here, they would bend quite a bit to make it happen for me."  I suppose it's 10% possible that they only want to bring you on because they're desperate to manipulate someone into the position who will feel contractually obligated to sell their product, or who believes in the product but not the company.  Eww.  Especially given that you're the founding sales rep., I'm fairly confident they want you to love everything about this opportunity, and even though there are some grim realities associated with startups, they want to face them WITH you, not just dump them on you.
3. Don't shortchange your needs and desires, just because you're respecting theirs.  Let's suppose shares really are better than options, and significantly so.  Don't be afraid to communicate disappointment, hope for a different arrangement, the need for reconciling their written statement with the previous commitment, etc.  It's totally ok to verbalize your needs kindly and wholeheartedly, while simultaneously acknowledging their limitations and the potential difficulties in granting your requests.

A quick principle to remember is to solve this problem as if you were seated side by side at a table looking down at a difficult challenge, rather than as if you were seated across from each other you each were the other's challenge.  That's the way you want to address all of your problems at your new company.  Make sure to start off on a great foot.

Answer (score 2):

It is normal for startups to offer options rather than shares.

The problem is that before they go public/private there is no market to bye sell the shares so exchanging the shares for actual currency is hard (and is not going to give you what the company says they are worth).

But on the other hand if you receive shares to the IRS these have value (its not their fault you can't convert the value) and thus you will owe taxes on them. This means before the company goes public these are a liability (as you have to pay taxes but can't convert to currency to pay those taxes).

Thus before going public startups usually offer options rather than shares. As options don't have any real value until you convert those options, there is no tax liability until you can sell.

---

The value of the shares. Unknowable until the company is sold.

But **usually** the company sets the option "grant" value at the company valuation (as filed in some federal form) divided by the number of common shares. This is why you hae the phrase `"the price will be set by the board of directors"` they follow this formula.

Your value is how much this value increases over time. Unless you are in the first 10 employees (or exceedingly lucky) this is not going to be a huge amount some nice icing in about 10 years time (if you stay that long (probably not)).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different take...

I think it depends on what the subjective understanding was during the phone call. *If* it was reasonably clear to both parties that the verbal agreement was that you would be given "shares," i.e. equity, *and then* in the follow-up written agreement of the offer letter, it was switched to options, which the other answers have established is not a significant part of or consideration in your total compensation package, then I think that act could very possibly indicate a less than sincere or honest act by the company.

But it depends very much on what your (and their) understanding was, how confident you were in your understanding that it would be shares vs. options, and how deliberate the discrepancy in the offer letter difference was.

In other words, if it was clear that you were told unambiguously that you would be given equity shares, and then without follow-up, mention, or further discussion, it was unceremoniously changed to options that have much less value, then that would be a big red flag that the company behind the offer is acting in a dishonest way right off the bat. And if so, that upfront dishonesty should be a big part of your consideration of whether to take the offer or go somewhere else.

Or beyond just blatant dishonesty, it could even potentially be a sign that the person making you the equity shares offer didn't have the authority to do so, was overridden in between their verbal offer and the actual written one, and didn't display the forthrightness to inform you of the distinction. But I've gotten off into speculation at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Employee stock options (ESOs) are probably not as bad as you think they are. Usually the expiration date is extremely long, ten years being common, so you can hold them like stock. They are usually issued at least a little "in the money", so any positive increase in the company value will show you profit. The chief downside is that they are not giving you a bunch of money up front in the value of the stock, but that is also an upside for income tax purposes. Also since they are not giving you a pile of money upfront there is often much more "leverage" on stock price upside with more shares in your control. Cashing out should theoretically require you to buy the stock, but employers will usually give you the difference between strike and market price directly.

If the job and offer are otherwise good, definitely make sure that the ESO plan is as bad as you think it is. The main difference is in the form of a (very deferred) signing bonus of the current value of the shares.